# How to group by result of the original result and returning in a same select query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to group by result of the original result and returning in a same select query?

I have a table `#t` with Bill Id and error's it went through on its workflow cycle. One Bill Id might have gone through Multiple times same error type or different error type.

I want to pick distinct error type for each bill id and get the Group By Count of Errors.

Based on different errors, error count, I need to get the error type count and the error type in the same table.

I am not sure how to do that. I kept the sample query and expected result in this posting.

```
create table #t 
(
    BillId int,
    StepName varchar(100),
    StepExec varchar(100),
    StepExecResult varchar(100),
    Created_date datetime
)

insert into #t 
values
    (1, 'Initiated', 'Taken Place','Pass', getdate()-10),
    (1, 'POS', 'Deadlock Error','Error', getdate()-9),
    (1, 'POS', 'Processed','Pass', getdate()-9),
    (1, 'Merchandise', 'Taken Place','Pass', getdate()-8),
    (1, 'verification', 'Webservice call error','Error', getdate()-7),
    (1, 'verification', 'Webservice call error','Error', getdate()-6),
    (1, 'verification', 'Webservice call','Pass', getdate()-5),
    (1, 'verification', 'Webservice Response','Error', getdate()-5),
    (1, 'verification', 'Webservice Response','Pass', getdate()-5),
    (1, 'verification', 'Timeout Error','Error', getdate()-5),
    (1, 'verification', 'Timeout Error','Error', getdate()-5),
    (1, 'verification', 'Timeout Error','Error', getdate()-5),
    (1, 'verification', '','Pass', getdate()-5),
    (1, 'Payment', 'calculationError','Error', getdate()-4),
    (1, 'Payment', 'calculationProcessed','Pass', getdate()-3),
    (1, 'Completed', 'Archived','Pass', getdate()-1),
    (2, 'Initiated', 'Taken Place','Pass', getdate()-10),
    (2, 'POS', 'Deadlock Error','Error', getdate()-9),
    (2, 'POS', 'Processed','Pass', getdate()-9),
    (2, 'Merchandise', 'Taken Place','Pass', getdate()-8),
    (2, 'verification', 'Webservice call error','Error', getdate()-7),
    (2, 'verification', 'Webservice call error','Error', getdate()-6),
    (2, 'verification', 'Webservice call','Pass', getdate()-5),
    (2, 'verification', 'Webservice Response','Error', getdate()-5),
    (2, 'verification', 'Webservice Response','Pass', getdate()-5),
    (2, 'verification', '','Pass', getdate()-5),
    (2, 'Payment', 'calculationProcessed','Pass', getdate()-3),
    (2, 'Completed', 'Archived','Pass', getdate()-1)

select * 
from #t
order by Created_date desc

select * 
from #t 
where StepExecResult = 'Error'

;With cte as
(
    select 
        *,
        row_number() over (partition by Billid,StepExec order by StepExecResult) as rownum
    from   
        #t 
    where 
        StepExecResult = 'Error'
)
select *  
from cte 
where rownum = 1

select 
    stepname, count(*) as ErrorCount 
from 
    #t
where 
    StepExecResult = 'Error'
group by 
    stepname
```

Expected output

```
StepName     TotalStepError     ErrorType       ErrorTypeCount
--------------------------------------------------------------
Payment             1           calculationError        1
POS                 2           Deadlock Error          2
verification        5           Timeout Error           1
verification        5           Webservice Response     2
verification        5           Webservice call error   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a distinct count of BillId grouped by StepName and StepExec for ErrorTypeCount.. Then just use window function to sum that count per StepName

```
SELECT  StepName ,
        SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT BillId)) OVER (PARTITION BY StepName) TotalStepError,
        StepExec ,
        COUNT(DISTINCT BillId) ErrorTypeCount
FROM    #t
WHERE   StepExecResult = 'Error'
GROUP BY StepName,
        StepExec
```

Comment: Thank you Jamie. That is so helpful .. !